# Как сделать привязку DataGrid.DataContext без фризов UI потока (C# WPF .NET 4.5)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Всех приветствую, возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, ибо я не могу решить =(

Все делал по инструкции: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/21.1.php
Я данные привязываю не к ListBox, как в примере, а к DataGrid:

```
DataGridMark.DataContext = db.AccountsMark.Local.ToBindingList();
```

И в этом моменте у меня происходит фриз UI.
И при дальнейших изменениях, типа :

```
db.AccountsMark.Add(acc);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Я тоже получаю фриз UI.

Я так понял, это из-за того что привязка не асинхронно делается.

**Вопрос:**

Как привязать асинхронно, или что сделать, чтоб не было фризов UI когда происходят изменения в db.AccountsMark

Comment: Создайте свойство типа `ObservableCollection<МоиДанные> КоллекцияИзБД` и прикрутите так `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding КоллекцияИзБД, IsAsync=True}" />`